# Some parameters are not getting saved when saving a model in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, attention-model, encoder-decoder

I have built an encoder-decoder model with attention for morph inflection generation. I am able to train the model and predict on test data but I am getting wrong predicting after loading a saved model
I am not getting any error during saving or loading but
When I load a saved model its predictions are completely wrong. It looks like some parameters are not getting saved.

I have tried to load and save the model using both techniques

1. using state_dict() eg. torch.save(encoder.state_dict(),'path')
2. saving complete model eg.torch.save(encoder,'path')

I have tried to save different classes one by one and also making a superclass that initiates all those class and then saving just superclass

but nothing seems to be working

Encoder class

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,vocab_size,embedding_size, encoder_hid_dem,decoder_hid_dem,bidirectional,dropout):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder_hid_dem  = encoder_hid_dem
        self.encoder_n_direction=1;
        self.bias = False
        self.dropout=dropout 
        if(bidirectional==True):
            self.encoder_n_direction=2;

        self.embedding_layer  = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_size, embedding_dim=embedding_size, padding_idx=0)
        self.GRU_layer        = nn.GRU(input_size=embedding_size, hidden_size=encoder_hid_dem, batch_first=True, bidirectional=bidirectional)
        self.fc               = nn.Linear(encoder_hid_dem*self.encoder_n_direction,decoder_hid_dem)
        self.dropout          = nn.Dropout(dropout)


    def forward(self, input_word):
        # print(input_word.size())
        #[batch_size    src_sent_lent]

        embed_out = self.embedding_layer(input_word)
        #[BATCH_SIZE    src_sent_lent   embedding_dim]

        embed_out = F.relu(embed_out)
        embed_out = self.dropout(embed_out)

        self.batch = embed_out.size()[0]

        # hidden =  self.init_hidden()
        GRU_out,hidden = self.GRU_layer(embed_out)


        # print(GRU_out.size())
        # print(hidd.size())

        #[BATCH_SIZE    sec_sent_len    n_direction*hid_dem]
        #[n_layer*n_direction   batch_size    hid_dem]

        #where the first hid_dim elements in the third axis are the hidden states from the top layer forward RNN, and the last hid_dim elements are hidden states from the top layer backward RNN

        #hidden is stacked [forward_1, backward_1, forward_2, backward_2, ...]
        #hidden [-2, :, : ] is the last of the forwards RNN 
        #hidden [-1, :, : ] is the last of the backwards RNN

        GRU_out = F.relu(GRU_out)
        hidden = torch.tanh(self.fc(torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:],hidden[-1,:,:]),dim=1)))

        # print(GRU_out.size())
        # print(hidden.size())

        #outputs = [batch_size    src sent len, encoder_hid_dim * n_direction]
        #hidden = [batch size, dec hid dim]
        return GRU_out,hidden

    def init_hidden(self):
        return (Variable(torch.eye(1, self.encoder_hid_dem)).unsqueeze(1).repeat(2, self.batch, 1).to(self.device))
```

Attention class

```
class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,encoder_hid_dem,decoder_hid_dem,bidirectional):
        super().__init__()
        self.enc_hid_dim = encoder_hid_dem
        self.dec_hid_dim = decoder_hid_dem
        self.encoder_n_direction=1;
        if(bidirectional==True):
            self.encoder_n_direction=2;

        self.attn = nn.Linear((encoder_hid_dem * self.encoder_n_direction) + decoder_hid_dem, decoder_hid_dem)
        self.v = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(decoder_hid_dem))

    def forward(self, hidden, encoder_outputs):

        #hidden = [batch size, dec hid dim]
        #encoder_outputs = [batch_size    ,src sent len, enc hid dim * encoder_n_direction]

        batch_size = encoder_outputs.shape[0]
        src_len    = encoder_outputs.shape[1]

        hidden = hidden.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, src_len, 1)

        #hidden          = [batch size, src sent len, dec hid dim]
        #encoder_outputs = [batch size, src sent len, enc hid dim * encoder_n_direction]

        energy = torch.tanh(self.attn(torch.cat((hidden, encoder_outputs), dim=2))) 
        #energy = [batch size, src sent len, dec hid dim]

        energy = energy.permute(0, 2, 1)
        #energy = [batch size, dec hid dim, src sent len]

        #v = [dec hid dim]
        v = self.v.repeat(batch_size, 1).unsqueeze(1)
        #v = [batch size, 1, dec hid dim]

        attention = torch.bmm(v, energy).squeeze(1)
        #attention= [batch size, src len]

        return F.softmax(attention, dim=1)
```

Decoder class

```
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, decoder_hid_dem, encoder_hid_dem, vocab_size,embedding_dim,attention,decoder_input_size,linear_input_size,bidirectional,dropout):
        super().__init__()      
        self.encoder_hid_dem=encoder_hid_dem
        self.decoder_hid_dem=decoder_hid_dem
        self.attention=attention
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.output_dim = vocab_size

        self.decoder_n_direction=1;
        if(bidirectional==True):
            self.decoder_n_direction=2;

        self.GRU_layer_out = nn.GRU(decoder_input_size,decoder_hid_dem)
        self.out_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=linear_input_size, out_features=vocab_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        #self.GRU_layer_out.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(decoder_input_size))

    def forward(self, feature, hidden,actual_word,encoder_outputs):

        feature = feature.unsqueeze(1)
        # print('decoder')
        # print(feature.size())
        #[batch_size    src_sent_lent=1   feat_size=6]

        # print(hidden.size())
        # [batch_size     dec_hid_dim]


        # print(actual_word.size())
        # [batch_size    src_sent_lent=1   embedding_dim]

        # print(encoder_outputs.size())
        # outputs = [batch_size    src sent len, encoder_hid_dim * encoder_n_directional]


        a = self.attention(hidden,encoder_outputs)
        #  print(a.size())
        # [batch_size    src_sent_len]

        a = a.unsqueeze(1)
        #a = [batch size, 1, src len] 

        weighted = torch.bmm(a,encoder_outputs)
        # print(weighted.size())
        # weighted = [batch size, 1, enc_hid_dim * encoder_n_direction]
        # if len(actual_word.size()) != 0:
        input_char = torch.cat((actual_word,feature,weighted),2) 
        # else:
        #     input_char = torch.cat((feature,weighted),2)

        input_char=input_char.permute(1,0,2)
        #  print(input_char.size())
        # [1    BATCH_SIZE      decoder_input_size]

        hidden = hidden.unsqueeze(0)
        # print(hidden.size())
        #[1 batch_size decoder_hid_dem]

        output, hidden = self.GRU_layer_out(input_char, hidden)

        # print(output.size())
        # [sent_len=1   batch_size  decoder_n_direction*decoder_hid_dem]
        # print(hidden.size())
        # [n_layer*n_direction    BATCH_SIZE      hid_dem]



        output = F.leaky_relu(output)
        output = self.dropout(output)

        output = torch.cat((output.squeeze(0),weighted.squeeze(1),actual_word.squeeze(1)),dim=1)
        pre_out = self.out_layer(output)
        predicted_output = F.log_softmax(pre_out, dim=1)

        # print(predicted_output.size())
        # [ batch_size vacab_size ]
        return predicted_output, hidden.squeeze(0)  

    def init_hidden(self, batch):
        return (Variable(torch.eye(1, self.decoder_hid_dem)).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, batch, 1).to(self.device),Variable(torch.eye(1, self.decoder_hid_dem)).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, batch, 1).to(self.device))
```

seq2seq class

```
class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,encoder,decoder,device):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.device = device

    def forward(self,input_word,output_word,features_word,teaching_forcing_ratio,limit):
        #print(input_word)
        #print(input_word.size())
        input_word = input_word.to(self.device)
        output_word = output_word.to(self.device)
        features_word = features_word.to(self.device)

        batch_size= input_word.size()[0]
        if(limit==0):
            max_len   = input_word.size()[1]
        else:
            max_len   = limit
        vocabsize = self.decoder.output_dim

        actual_word = self.encoder.embedding_layer(torch.tensor(char_to_index['<sos>']).view(1, -1).to(self.device)).repeat(batch_size, 1, 1)
        encoder_outputs,hidden = self.encoder(input_word)
        features=features_word[:,:]

        predicted_word = torch.zeros(max_len,batch_size,vocabsize).to(self.device)

        for t in range(1,max_len):
            output,hidden=self.decoder(features, hidden,actual_word,encoder_outputs)
            #print(output.size())
            predicted_word[t] = output 
            topv, topi = output.topk(1)
            bs = topi.size()[0]
            temp2 = torch.zeros(0,1,300).to(self.device)
            for row in range(bs):
                index = topi[row][0].item()
                temp = self.encoder.embedding_layer(torch.tensor(index).view(1, -1).to(self.device))
                temp2 = torch.cat((temp2,temp))

            teacher_force = random.random() < teaching_forcing_ratio
            if teacher_force == 1:
                actual_word = self.encoder.embedding_layer(output_word[:,t]).unsqueeze(1)
            else:
                actual_word = temp2

        return predicted_word
```

and this code is used to save and load model

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.pt')
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pt'))
```

I want that when I run my model on pre-trained weights, it should predict correctly acc to those weights

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code for saving/loading parameters is wrong. The loading and saving model parameters are pretty straight-forward. In your case, it should be:

```
# loading
saved_params = torch.load(
    filename, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage
)
s2s.load_state_dict(saved_params)

# saving
params = s2s.state_dict()
torch.save(params, filename)
```

---

**[Update]**

You need to make the `Seq2Seq` class a derived class of PyTorch's `nn.Module` just like your encoder/decoder classes. Otherwise, you can't use the `state_dict()` method. You can assume `Seq2Seq` class is like a container that contains your whole network, although it does not have any learnable weights itself.

Comment: I have tried what u asked for but it is giving an error " 'Seq2Seq' object has no attribute 'state_dict' ". and actally it should because S2S class has no learnable params in itself.

Comment: I tried this it solved the previous error but the real problem still exists. Model is getting saved and loaded but after loading, the model is not predicting correctly. I think the problem is that there is something in the code whose values are not getting saved. I can provide the link to the whole code if u want.